# Filter issues by the user who closed them

Tags: jira

I have started using Jira just recently and I am having trouble with the Issue Navigator.
I want to filter the issues so that the list shows only those that were closed by a specific user. I get to filter the issues by their status and/or resolution but not by the user that last updated them (that would be, the one that closed them).

I'm sure the answer is obvious but I can't seem to find out how to do it!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry, but the answer from Daria Trainor is not correct. You find Issues, where the status is closed and one of the transistions where made by the "username"

The correct one have to be:

`status was closed BY 'username'`

also possible:

`status changed to Closed BY 'username'`

then you also find issues, in a differnt state

if your workflow is more complex you can also limit like this:

`status changed FROM Resolved to Closed BY 'username'`

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-CHANGED is the place to start for this kind of filter

Answer (score 28):

You can use 'status changed by':

```
status = Closed and status changed by username
```

From the [JQL documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching):

> The "CHANGED" operator is used to find issues that have a value which
> had changed for the specified field.
>
> This operator has the following optional predicates:
>
> - AFTER "date"
> - BEFORE "date"
> - BY "username"
> - DURING ("date1","date2")
> - ON "date"
> - FROM "oldvalue" TO "newvalue"
>
> (Note: This operator can be used with the Assignee, Fix Version, Priority, Reporter,
> Resolution and Status fields only.)

Comment: a small note- if the users can change issues after issues were closed, the query will show the last person who edit it, whether that was an edit or closing the issue. Still, +1 from me for the nice and short JQL query!

Comment: Bit off topic, but note that when you end up using BEFORE and AFTER in the same query, then you should consider using DURING instead of combining the former two. Reason for that is, that in bigger jira instances "BEFORE <some date>" would potentially return almost all issues hence resulting in humongous result being processed. However DURING takes two dates into account at once and therefore will not result in sub-query that takes everything since the start of your jira in results.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer is incorrect, as pointed out by Gambotic.

Comment: Not working, it seems returning all closed bug where at some point username has made a status changed, looking in `Transitions` tab of `Activity` part of an issue I have for instance for one `username open -> resolved` and `otheruser resolved -> closed`, this is then actually not `usename` that closed this issue, prefer @Gambotic answer