# Advanced search in JIRA

Tags: jira

I want to create a query in JIRA and search for all issues closed by me. Simple search does not allow to do this but in advanced search I'd like to write JQL query but I don't know if JIRA has fields like username and transaction like 'close'
In other words how could in JIRA I write the query to search for all issues closed by user 'Joe' ?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359357/filter-issues-by-the-user-who-closed-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

status was in (resolved, closed) BY joe_username

OR for yourself

status was in (resolved, closed) BY currentUser()

Answer (score 0):

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching

Cntrl-F for this Phrase
"status WAS "Resolved" BY jsmith"