# How to filter which assignee changed the status of the action item?

Tags: jira, jql

There are 1200 issue in my db. I want to filter who changed the status of the issue from Resolved to Close. How can I filter this using JQL?

Comment: Take a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359357/filter-issues-by-the-user-who-closed-them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQL just allows you to look for "Issues" not for people. So if you need to find users that made any action, you should try with a script.

Regards