# JIRA / JQL: How to *negate* "status changed to closed by" in a JQL filter (so as to only look for issues *not* closed by user X)?

Tags: jira, jql

Building on [Filter issues by the user who closed them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359357/filter-issues-by-the-user-who-closed-them), how to modify this query to give issues **not** closed by user a and user b?

Answer (score 1):

Use "**AND NOT status changed BY**" like so:

```
status changed BEFORE  endOfWeek('-1') AND NOT status changed BY membersOf("QA")
```

(cf. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Search-for-issues-where-status-was-changed-by-other-members-than/qaq-p/761756)